# Haskell Either with fixed types

Tags: haskell

I have two types, assume they both have monoid implementations. Is there a way to have another type that will be specified to contain an X or a Y? Or is this not the right way to go about this?

```
data X = X [Int]
data Y = Y Double
```

Comment: Why not use `Either X Y`?

Comment: I want to instance behavior on it. maybe newtype either x y?

Comment: newtype would work: `newtype EitherXY = EitherXY (Either X Y)`

Comment: ah lovely, thank you.

Comment: Maybe update your question to reflect that you need an instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OP has clarified in the comments that they want 'instance behaviour' for some type `Either X Y`. Typically, you'd use a `newtype` in this situation:

```
newtype EitherXY = EitherXY (Either X Y)
```

In case you're not already aware, `newtypes` can have a record-like unwrapping function.

```
newtype EitherXY = EitherXY { unwrap :: Either X Y } deriving (...)
```

You may also auto-derive certain type classes (as with data declarations). The set of derivable classes depends on the compiler version and the set of enabled extensions. I won't [elaborate](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes) on it here.

Answer (score 9):

It's probably better to just do

```
data X_Or_Y = InX X | InY Y
```

This type is isomorphic to Either X Y, but it's easier to work with/pattern match on than a newtype, since it only has 2 layers of nested constructors

Comment: Good point, but all the combinators available for `Either` might come in handy...